# What is direction of indexes ar MongoEngine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Mongoengine has `meta` option and the nested `indexes` option. I know it can does increase selecting by queries. But can somebody to expand an information about the

> direction

? May be there is a some tips about it. [Here](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=indexes#indexes) is too small information

Comment: + should be ascending and - descending if it follows MongoDB convention. I would try both to confirm.

Comment: direction is useful in compound indexes when you are doing sort operations. Otherwise index on { key : 1 } or { key : -1 } doesn't have any performance difference.

Comment: I would suggest reading through the following page on indexes in MongoDB. It provides a good overview and should provide the background you are looking for: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies - `fieldname` is ascending order and `-fieldname` is descending.

I have updated the documentation.